# Aapache Geode for data replication

Tags: low-latency, geode

We need to maintain and modify an in-memory hash table from within a single java process. We also need to persist it, so that its contents can be recovered after a crash, deploy or when the machine running the application fails.
We have tight latency requirements.

Would Apache Geode fit our requirements? We will run two additional nodes, which can be used on application startup to populate the hash table values.

Answer (score 0):

Geode is a key value distributed cache, kind of like a hash table on steroids, so yes, it would fit your requirements.

You can choose to persist your data, or not.

You can have n nodes populating your data managed by a locator process that will auto distribute to all nodes, or a set of nodes, on the same machine, or on n other machines.